# How can I insert data into two or more tables at once in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I am trying to instert data from an html form using php into mysql database. Only one table(customer table) is being inserted and not package table as well.Am asking for help on how I could insert into both tables at once. Here is the code...Please help

```
<?php
include "includes/connection.php";

//Customer Table
$firstName = $_POST['inputFirstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['inputLastName'];
$gender = $_POST['inputGender'];
$address = $_POST['inputAddress'];
$mobileNumber = $_POST['inputMobilePhone'];
$workAddress = $_POST['inputAddress'];
$age = $_POST['inputAge'];

//Package Information
$PackageName = $_POST['inputPackageName'];
$PackageWeight = $_POST['inputPackageWeight'];
$PackagePrice = $_POST['inputPackagePrice'];
$DepartureDestination = $_POST['inputDepartureDestination'];
$finalDestination = $_POST['inputFinalDestination'];
//$DeliveryOption = $_POST['inputDeliveryOption'];

//Receiver Information

$receiverFirstName = $_POST['inputReceiverFirstName'];
$receiverLastName = $_POST['inputReceiverLastName'];
$receiverAddress = $_POST['inputReceiverAddress'];
$receiverPhone = $_POST['inputReceiverPhone'];




if(!$_POST['submit']) {
    echo "Please fill out the form";
    header ('Location: user.php');
}
else {


        $sql = "INSERT INTO cus_sender (SenderID,StaffID,SenderFirstName,SennderLastName,Address,Phone,SEX,Age,Time)
                                        VALUES (NULL,NULL,:firstName,:lastName,:address,:mobileNumber,:gender,:age,'')";
        $sql2= "INSERT INTO package(PID,SenderID,StaffID,PackageName,PackageWeight,Price,DepartureTown,DeliveryTown,DeliveryMethod)
                                        VALUES (NULL,NULL,NULL,:PackageName,:PackageWeight,:PackagePrice,:DepartureDestination,:finalDestination)"; //Add delivery option

$q = $db->prepare($sql); 

$q->execute(array(':firstName'=>$firstName, 
             ':lastName'=>$lastName,
             ':address'=>$address,
             ':mobileNumber'=>$mobileNumber,
             ':gender'=>$gender,
             ':age'=>$age)); 

$q2 = $db->prepare($sql2); 

$q2->execute(array(':PackagePrice'=>$PackageName, 
             ':PackageWeight'=>$PackageWeight,
             ':PackagePrice'=>$PackagePrice,
             ':DepartureDestination'=>$DepartureDestination,
             ':finalDestination'=>$finalDestination));
             //':DeliveryOption'=>$DeliveryOption)); To be added later


echo "<p>Customer has been added!</p>";

header ('Location: http://localhost/BNW/newCustomer.php');


}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP MySQLi Multiple Inserts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488033/php-mysqli-multiple-inserts)

Answer (score 0):

```
By this way you can insert values in more than one table with single query.

<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'test');

$start = microtime(true);
$a = 'a';
$b = 'b';

$sql = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO multi (a,b) VALUES(?, ?)');
$sql->bind_param('ss', $a, $b);
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
{
    $a = chr($i % 1);
    $b = chr($i % 2);
    $sql->execute();
}
$sql->close();

echo microtime(true) - $start;

$db->close();

?>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but. There is a part i don't understand. If we are inserting into (a,b) how to i then arrange the values. As in VALUES(?,?), how then can i arrange the attributes from both the tables? Using PDO